# A very specify HTML/JS syntax error caused by un-matching tag

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

This line is breaking code highlighting in HTML/JS syntax highlighter in Gedit editor. This is a variable declared in the `<script>` tag:

```
var HTML_FRG6 = '"/></li>';
```

I know something's wrong with it, I just cant figure out what!

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>News</title> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css-js/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" /> 
<script src="css-js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="css-js/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

    <script>
     // constants     

      var COMMA = ',';
      var EMPTY = '';
      var REFRESH = 'refresh';
      var LI = 'li';
      var PAR = 'p';
      var ID = 'id';
      var ITEM = 'item';
      var TITLE = 'title';
      var CATEGORY = 'category';
      var DESCR = 'description';
      var CAT_ = 'cat_';
      var _D = '_d';
      var _LI = '_li';
      var _A = '_a';
      var GET = 'GET';
      var XML = 'xml';
      var HTML_FRG1 = '<li id="';
      var HTML_FRG2 = '"><h3><a id="';
      var HTML_FRG3 = '"  href="#">';
      var HTML_FRG4 = '</a></h3><p id="';
      var HTML_FRG5 = '"></p><a href="#" data-transition="slideup" id="';
      var HTML_FRG6 = '"/></li>';
      var HTML_FRG7 = '<p>';
      var HTML_FRG8 = '</p><hr></hr>';    
      var NEWS_URI = 'bridge.php?fwd=http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/';
      var TWO_SECONDS = 2000;

  </script>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Lines after `var HTML_FRG6 = '"/></li>';` are not being highlighted. I wonder why?

Comment: Post the relevant code which was broken.

Comment: These information is not enough to provide an answer. Please tell us about the error you get.

Comment: There's nothing "wrong" with the code you posted, syntax-wise.

Comment: @JanTuroň I just posted the whole part. Sorry!

Comment: @WesleyMurch There is definitely something wrong with that line. Gedit identifies the syntax of everything else after that line perfectly when I remove it!

Comment: Remove `<script>` from your post, you will see there is no syntax error.

Comment: @WesleyMurch I dont think thats a good idea seeing as this is (I think at least) inline js within an index.html file. Just to make that clear I edited the code one more time to include the ending </script> line.

Comment: Nevermind, we misunderstand each other.

Comment: Ok, I've cut out all the functions and other stuff and posted the entire relevant section!

Comment: Just a couple of questions: 1) Does the code actually break in the browser or do you just think something is wrong because your editor shows the code funky? If there is a problem in the browser, what error message do you see? 2) Is this the exact code you have? If so, you don't have a closing head tag and no opening body tag, as well as an extra closing div tag.

Comment: @Steve, No error in the browser. It runs with the rest of the stuff in it but it freezes on a loading page after a certain function. I just assumed something was wrong with that line because gedit's highlighting cuts off right after it. But works if i remove it or comment it out

Answer (score 0):

My lucky guess would be that the `var HTML_FRG6 = '"/></li>';` line contains only one `"` sign which is the last one in the script, so everything after this is considered string in code highlighting. If it's true, this is just Gedit highlighting error (the syntax is fine) and the solution would be ad-hoc lucky guess. One of these could help:

- put `var fix = '"';` after the line
- put `var fix = '""';` after the line
- move the line one line above

Answer (score 0):

Try using it like this

.   var HTML_FRG6 = "/"/>";
Its the same thing but the " is escaped.